# mongodb pull function why not working in my situation?

Tags: mongodb, react-native, pull

i make simple board app. but i face scrab problem.

i want to pull data in scrabContent when people unscrab. but it doesnt' work. help me plz..

My Schema looks like this. scrabContent means contents that i scrab. So, when i scrab some contents, they are stored in scrabContent.

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required:true,
        unique: true,
    },
    follower : [String],
    following : [String],
    boardBookmark: [],
    scrabContent: [],
    songs: [],
    songsView: {
        type: Number,
        default :0,
    },
    profileImage: {
        type: String,
    }
});
```

this is schema data example.

```
{
  follower: [],
  following: [],
  boardBookmark: [
    {
      name: 'asd',
      introduction: 'dsadad',
      boardId: '603a4e485d99d993e0bfdfee'
    }
  ],
  scrabContent: [
    {
      commentsNum: 3,
      likes: [],
      image: [Array],
      isDeleted: false,
      _id: 603b67e1904622ca9ee2cddb,
      title: 'ㄴㅁㅇㄹㅁㄴㄹㅁ',
      content: 'ㅁㅇㄴㄹㅁㄹㅁㄴㄹㅁㄴㄹ',
      postUser: 'umpa',
      postUserId: 603751786587acfbf1052d34,
      boardId: 603a4e485d99d993e0bfdfee,
      time: '2021/02/28 18:52:32',
      __v: 0
    },
    {
      commentsNum: 5,
      likes: [Array],
      image: [Array],
      isDeleted: false,
      _id: 603b09f509dcb8b594c1f015,
      title: '테스트',
      content: 'ㅋㅋ',
      postUser: 'umpa',
      postUserId: 603751786587acfbf1052d34,
      boardId: 603a4e485d99d993e0bfdfee,
      time: '2021/02/28 12:11:47',
      __v: 0
    }
  ],
  songs: [
    {
      id: '1469319400',
      type: 'songs',
      href: '/v1/catalog/kr/songs/1469319400',
      attributes: [Object],
      name: 'LOVE AGAIN'
    },
    {
      id: '1265893529',
      type: 'songs',
      href: '/v1/catalog/kr/songs/1265893529',
      attributes: [Object],
      name: 'Get You (feat. Kali Uchis)'
    },
    {
      id: '1265893532',
      type: 'songs',
      href: '/v1/catalog/kr/songs/1265893532',
      attributes: [Object],
      name: 'Best Part (feat. H.E.R.)'
    },
    {
      id: '1356070221',
      type: 'songs',
      href: '/v1/catalog/kr/songs/1356070221',
      attributes: [Object],
      name: 'Daniel'
    },
    {
      id: '1438474485',
      type: 'songs',
      href: '/v1/catalog/kr/songs/1438474485',
      attributes: [Object],
      name: 'Falling'
    }
  ],
  songsView: 0,
  _id: 603a84d9760444a652d2cc72,
  email: 'test',
  password: '$2b$10$w8b85O6KQwGIZ0D1x0TGle.qofoEC43OKI5cMSf7tfqld12fSUWlu',
  name: 'test',
  __v: 0
}
```

and this is server code to pull. req.user._id means User Schema's _id(in this case: 603a84d9760444a652d2cc72). and req.params.id means Content _id(in this case: 603b67e1904622ca9ee2cddb) in ScrabContent.

```
router.delete('/deleteScrabContent/:id', requireAuth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.user._id}, {$pull: {scrabContent: {_id: req.params.id}}}, {new: true});
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(422).send(err.message);
  }
});
```

i don't know why scrabContent doesn't work.. help me T^T

Comment: Have you tried with `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)` instead of passing the string value?

Comment: Wow!!!! It works well. Awesome. Thanks a lot::::))) have a good day